# Add children to parent from form constructed via ajax Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, insert, parent-child

I have the following form:

[image]

When the user selects a product from the dropdown, a ajax is triggered to find the inventory of the single product to append the details to a table.

The user can attach a product detail to the order.

Finally I get something like that:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"xmlzMouWp0QGUnpKeawQ8OCPJ/GlF2bp0kn97ra2Qyb7TgsCkXmJEGD1l/oZitn+VPVJRc8x79/kTUtgbbDr0A==", "order"=>{"customer_search"=>"", "customer_id"=>"2", "product_search"=>"", "order_detail"=>[{"product_id"=>"10", "product_detail_id"=>"13", "price_id"=>"12"}, {"product_id"=>"1", "product_detail_id"=>"8", "price_id"=>"11"}], "subtotal"=>"111990", "tax"=>"0", "comission"=>"0", "total"=>"111990"}, "product_list"=>"1", "button"=>""}
```

My code to create the order is working, but I can not add the details.

**Orders controller**

```
  def create

    # Creates the order removing the order details from the hash
    @order = Order.create(order_params.except!(:order_detail))

    # Set all the details into an empty array
    order_details_attributes = order_params[:order_detail]

    order_details_attributes.each do |order_detail_attributes|

      # Fill the params with order_id and creates the detail
      order_detail_attributes["order_id"] = @order.id
      @order_detail = OrderDetail.create(order_detail_attributes)

    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def order_params
     params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :subtotal, :tax, :comission, :total, :invoice, :shipping_id, :order_detail, order_details_attributes: [:product_id, :product_detail_id, :price_id])
  end
```

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
order_details_attributes = order_params[:order].delete(:order_detail)
```

What could be bad? I really need help :(

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order_params` doesn't have key `:order`, it only has keys you specified in `permit` method when defined `order_params`. Actually, you don't need to manually create children records, as Rails can do this automatically. Check this out: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

You just need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_details` in Order model, fill `order_details_attributes` param when creating an order (currently you fill `order_detail`, you need to fix you form for it to be `order_details_attributes`, because this is one of Rails conventions, or you can use `fields_for` helper for this). Then you just create Order in standard way, like `@order = Order.new(order_params)` and `@order.save`, and you'll get order and order details created together.

This is a really messy thing in Rails. I can only recommend you to read the link I posted and use Google to find some tutorials.

As to the error you get:

```
undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
```

There is no `:order` key in `order_params`. It is in `params`, but not in `order_params`, because you called `require(:order)`. So `order_params` returns only the keys you specified in `permit` method. But `:order_detail` will be empty, as you didn't describe it as an array with certain keys (like you did for `order_details_attributes`).

So, your problem is that you tried to implement nested attributes, but you pass `:order_detail` instead of `:order_details_attributes` (hm, but you still have it in strong params) and try to create children relations manually.  Don't do this, just use what Rails provides to you.

There are 2 ways:

1. You continue to use `order_detail` param. In this case you need to change `order_params` in controller to look like so:

   params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :subtotal, :tax, :comission, :total, :invoice, :shipping_id, order_detail: [:product_id, :product_detail_id, :price_id])

(just replace `order_details_attributes` with `order_detail`)

Then instead of

```
order_details_attributes = order_params[:order].delete(:order_detail)
```

you do

```
order_details_attributes = order_params[:order_detail]
```

(you don't need `delete` here as `order_params` is a method that returns a hash)

And leave rest controller code as it is now. And you don't need nested attributes, as you don't use it (bad way).

2. You fully use nested attributes. I described in a comment below how to do this. You also need to tweak you jquery code to generate `order_details_attributes` instead of `order_detail`.

Comment: The accepts_nested_attributes_for is added, Its not the problem. I dont understand what are you trying to explain between order_details_attributes and order_detail

Comment: To automatically create children object Rails requires a parameter that has the following pattern:
`[relation_name]_attributes`
In your case it's `order_details_attributes` (Order has_many :order_details). And according to the parameters you posted, you pass `order_detail` param instead. Then in controller you manipulate with it an try to create children relations. You don't need to do this, just fill `order_details_attributes` instead of `order_detail`.

Comment: I updated my answer. Put it simply, all you need is:
1. Add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_details` to Order model

2. Pass order details as `:order_details_attributes` array of hashes

3. Have `order_params` like this:
`params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :subtotal, :tax, :comission, :total, :invoice, :shipping_id, order_details_attributes: [:product_id, :product_detail_id, :price_id])`

4. Create order like this:
@order = Order.new(order_params)
if @order.save
...
(no need to create order details manually)

Everything should work.

Comment: But I generate the order_detail via jquery, I fill the table when the user add a product detail to the order...

Comment: I updated the answer, check it out. It should be clear now what to do.

Comment: Is workiiiiiiiiiing! But I had to do some changes on the create method, check the details. BTW, thank you so so so so much

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful for you. But I recommend you to read the link I posted in my answer and do some googling if necessary, cause nested attributes is a bit messy thing. You don't need to create order details manually, Rails already has tools for this. This is what it's all about – conventions: learn the rules, stick to them and you'll get huge profit. Good luck.